# Drawing tool in Python

Tags: application-development, python

I am trying to implement drawing concept like line,rectangle,pencil and brush tool in Gtk.Textview . Is it possible to draw into Gtk.textview?

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: @zignd : this questions is ontopic here

Comment: Try gdk(Gimp drawing toolkit)

Comment: Not GDK, you should use Cairo for drawing in GTK.

Comment: @Timo : sorry for mistake, BTW post it as answer :)

Comment: @Tachyons: it's not really an answer, just a hint. Maybe I'll try later on how to draw stuff on a textview. If time permits...

Answer (score 0):

I found some links, that might help you.

https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-app-devel-list/2008-October/msg00098.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027379/draw-lines-on-gtk-textview